# Go/Travel from a place

Tags: word-difference

A sentence like this:

> She's going to a fashion show here in the city tomorrow. She is sleeping here so she won't have to **travel** from Riverdale in the morning.

If I replace *travel* with *go*, will there be any difference in meaning?

Comment: The issue is using *go* vs. *come*, since these are unidirectional terms, while *travel* is bidirectional (direction is not specified). First, you need to specify where *here* in "She is sleeping here" is (the city, Riverdale, or somewhere else).

Comment: @user3169 Well, there're 3 different places, here is A, Riverdale is B and the place holding the fashion show is C.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I added some specifics to your example:

> She's going to a fashion show in the city tomorrow. She is sleeping at my house (between Riverdale and the city) so she won't have to *travel* from Riverdale in the morning.

Well, you can't use *go* or *come* because she is now at a mid-point. *travel* is OK, but you could also use *drive* or *leave*:

> She's going to a fashion show here in the city tomorrow. She is sleeping here so she won't have to **drive from/leave** Riverdale in the morning.

Comment: So if there're three different places A, B and C and I'm at A now, I should use _go_ from A to B/C, use _travel_ from B to C or C to B.  In other words, If I'm at the starting point of the path, I can use _go_, otherwise use _travel_ instead, Right?

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies in the question only! You only said she's *going to* the Fashion Show. So, the correct choice is *go.*

On the other hand, you are clear in your context and want to emphasize that due to the distance, she has preferred staying nearby the venue. Depending on the *context,* it is *traveling* and that's why, *travel* goes better there. *Go from* is also possible but the context changes: *'You cannot go from here.'*

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Your concern is *distance* in the second half of the sentence and that's the reason  why she's staying there. Clearly, when it is about *distance,* you use *travel.* *Go* won't fit.